# Exploratory Data Analysis with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can i group continuous data (like a tenure column showing different months for each row) into categories shown in a separate column using pandas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd

# Make fake data
dates = {"tenure": [datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), datetime.date(2020, 1, 24), datetime.date(2020, 5, 13),
                    datetime.date(2021, 5, 23), datetime.date(2022, 5, 5), datetime.date(2020, 3, 16),
                    datetime.date(2020, 5, 28), datetime.date(2020, 9, 23), datetime.date(2020, 12, 28),
                    datetime.date(2021, 10, 12)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dates)
```

| tenure |
| --- |
| 2020-01-31 |
| 2020-01-24 |
| 2020-05-13 |
| 2021-05-23 |
| 2022-05-05 |
| 2020-03-16 |
| 2020-05-28 |
| 2020-09-23 |
| 2020-12-28 |
| 2021-10-12 |

```py
# Make months to group by
df["tenure"] = pd.to_datetime(df.tenure)
df["month"] = df.tenure.dt.month_name()
```

| tenure | month |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 00:00:00 | January |
| 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | January |
| 2020-05-13 00:00:00 | May |
| 2021-05-23 00:00:00 | May |
| 2022-05-05 00:00:00 | May |
| 2020-03-16 00:00:00 | March |
| 2020-05-28 00:00:00 | May |
| 2020-09-23 00:00:00 | September |
| 2020-12-28 00:00:00 | December |
| 2021-10-12 00:00:00 | October |

```py
# Group by months and show "different months for each row"
df = (df
      .sort_values("tenure")
      .groupby("month")["tenure"]
      .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True))
      .unstack()
      .reset_index())
```

| month | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| December | 2020-12-28 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT | NaT |
| January | 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | 2020-01-31 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT |
| March | 2020-03-16 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT | NaT |
| May | 2020-05-13 00:00:00 | 2020-05-28 00:00:00 | 2021-05-23 00:00:00 | 2022-05-05 00:00:00 |
| October | 2021-10-12 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT | NaT |
| September | 2020-09-23 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT | NaT |

OR perhaps something like this?:

```py
# Group by months and show "different months for each row"
df = (df.sort_values("tenure")
        .groupby("month")["tenure"]
        .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True))
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
        .T)
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

| December | January | March | May | October | September |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-28 00:00:00 | 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | 2020-03-16 00:00:00 | 2020-05-13 00:00:00 | 2021-10-12 00:00:00 | 2020-09-23 00:00:00 |
| NaT | 2020-01-31 00:00:00 | NaT | 2020-05-28 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT |
| NaT | NaT | NaT | 2021-05-23 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT |
| NaT | NaT | NaT | 2022-05-05 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT |